# TableView not showing anything after keying in the second letter into search bar

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

I used json parsing and managed to fetch information from a website and show it in the Table View. I managed to set up the search bar such that it searches for the text. However when i key in my second letter there is nothing in the table view even though there is words starting with the two letters. I have added my code below.

```
@implementation EventsTableViewController
@synthesize searchBar, filteredEventsArray, eventNamesArray, isFiltered, eventsDictionary;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.eventNamesArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    self.eventsDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self searchForEvents];
}

//Json Parsing
- (void)searchForEvents
{


    NSString *eventsSearchUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/1562818803553764290/posts?key=AIzaSyBTOxz-vPHgzIkw9k88hDKd99ILTaXTt0Y"];
    NSURL *eventsSearchUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:eventsSearchUrlString];
    NSURLRequest *eventsSearchUrlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:eventsSearchUrl];

    NSURLSession *sharedUrlSession = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *searchEventsTask =
    [sharedUrlSession dataTaskWithRequest:eventsSearchUrlRequest completionHandler:
     ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
     {
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                        ^{
                            [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

                            if(error)
                            {
                                UIAlertView *searchAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Please check your internet connection" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                                [searchAlertView show];
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                NSString *resultString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                NSLog(@"Search results: %@", resultString);

                                NSError *jsonParseError = nil;
                                NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&jsonParseError];

                                if(jsonParseError)
                                {
                                    UIAlertView *jsonParseErrorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:jsonParseError.localizedDescription delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                                    [jsonParseErrorAlert show];
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    for(NSString *key in jsonDictionary.keyEnumerator)
                                    {
                                        NSLog(@"First level key: %@", key);
                                    }

                                    [self.eventNamesArray removeAllObjects];
                                    [self.eventsDictionary removeAllObjects];

                                    NSArray *searchResultsArray = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"items"];
                                    //NSLog(@"test%@",searchResultsArray);


                                    for(NSDictionary *eventsInfoDictionary in searchResultsArray)
                                    {
                                        Events *event = [[Events alloc] init];
                                        event.eventName = [eventsInfoDictionary objectForKey:@"title"];
                                        event.eventDescription =[eventsInfoDictionary objectForKey:@"content"];

                                        NSLog(@"Event Name : %@",event.eventName);
                                        NSLog(@"Event Description : %@",event.eventDescription);

                                        NSString *eventsAsStrings = [event.eventName substringToIndex:1];
                                        NSMutableArray *eventsInArray = [self.eventsDictionary objectForKey:eventsAsStrings];

                                        if(!eventsInArray)
                                        {
                                            eventsInArray = [NSMutableArray array];
                                            [self.eventNamesArray addObject:eventsAsStrings];
                                        }

                                        [eventsInArray addObject:event];

                                        [self.eventsDictionary setObject:eventsInArray forKey:eventsAsStrings];

                                        if ([event.eventDescription containsString:@"<br />"]) {
                                            NSString* eventDescrip = event.eventDescription;
                                            NSString* stringWithoutHTMLtags = [eventDescrip stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<br />" withString:@""];
                                            event.eventDescription = stringWithoutHTMLtags;
                                        }
                                        NSLog(@"Event Name : %@",event.eventName);
                                        NSLog(@"Event Description : %@",event.eventDescription);

                                    }

                                    [self.eventNamesArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(Events *obj1, Events *obj2) {
                                        Events *time1 = obj1;
                                        Events *time2 = obj2;
                                        if (time1 > time2) {
                                            return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
                                        }
                                        else if (time1 < time2) {
                                            return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
                                        }
                                        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
                                    }];
                                    [self.tableView reloadData];
                                }
                            }
                        });
     }];

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
    [searchEventsTask resume];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    if (searchText.length == 0) {
        isFiltered = NO;
    }
    else {
        isFiltered = YES;
    }
    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF BEGINSWITH[c] %@",searchText];
    self.filteredEventsArray = [eventNamesArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

//- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
 //   [resign fi]
//}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    if (isFiltered == YES) {
        return filteredEventsArray.count;
    }
    else {
        return self.eventNamesArray.count;
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSArray *eventsWithFirstLetter;
    if (isFiltered == YES) {
        NSString *firstLetter = [self.filteredEventsArray objectAtIndex:section];
        eventsWithFirstLetter = [self.eventsDictionary objectForKey:firstLetter];
        return eventsWithFirstLetter.count;
    }
    else {
        NSString *firstLetter = [self.eventNamesArray objectAtIndex:section];
        eventsWithFirstLetter = [self.eventsDictionary objectForKey:firstLetter];
        return eventsWithFirstLetter.count;
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"eventTitleCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    Events *event;
    if (isFiltered == YES) {
        NSString *firstLetter = [self.filteredEventsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        NSArray *eventsWithFirstLetter = [self.eventsDictionary objectForKey:firstLetter];
        event = [eventsWithFirstLetter objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = event.eventName;
    }
    else {
        NSString *firstLetter = [self.eventNamesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        NSArray *eventsWithFirstLetter = [self.eventsDictionary objectForKey:firstLetter];
        event = [eventsWithFirstLetter objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = event.eventName;
    }
    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *firstLetter = [self.eventNamesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *eventsWithFirstLetter = [self.eventsDictionary objectForKey:firstLetter];
    Events *event = [eventsWithFirstLetter objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
    DescriptionViewController *descriptionViewController = (DescriptionViewController*)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"descriptionController"];
    descriptionViewController.eventNameDesc = event.eventDescription;
    descriptionViewController.navigationItem.title = event.eventName;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:descriptionViewController animated:YES];

}



@end
```

Comment: Please log the contents of filteredEventsArray at the end of - (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText so that you can decide if it's a problem in the UI or with the predicate.

Comment: when i key in my second letter there is nothing in my log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read this correctly, you only store one letter in the `eventNamesArray`: `NSString *eventsAsStrings = [event.eventName substringToIndex:1];`.

So the predicate `self.filteredEventsArray = [eventNamesArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];` will only match, if you type one letter.

So one simple solution would be to store the complete event names in their own array, so that you can match against those.

Comment: so do i change the substringToIndex:1

Comment: Well, to match this predicate, you will need an array containing the complete event names. You can construct this easily.